# Build a regression model with very high Variance

Tags: r, regression

I have a Data-set that consists of 500 variables. It's a regression problem where the dependent variable (Y) varies from 0 to 25700.

Count of Dependent Variables that is 0 : 60% of the data

Most of the Dependent variable ranges from 0 - 1000. But for 20 incidences, Dependent variable ranges from 1000 to 25700. Only two records are more than 20000. Can't treat these record as Outlier, as it makes business sense. Can some-one please help me how to proceed with this problem.

Comment: Is that count data? Then you need to account for that, e.g., by using a GLM or GAM. Is your data zero-inflated, i.e., is there a process that distinguishes zero and non-zero and then another process that determines the non-zero value? You need to talk to a statistician.

Comment: You should provide a clear question as to what you want help with. Are you trying to reduce the R^2? Have you not yet run a regression? You tagged both linear and non-linear regression, which is it.

Comment: I have run a regression model (Linear as well as Non Linear). But RMSE comes to be pretty huge.